# How can i get Vimeo Video Id with JSON format like YouTube api

Tags: android, json, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

With the help of YouTube API i get the data of a channel.
But in Vimeo Video how can i get that ?
I want some like this => 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=Channel_id&order=date&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of a Channel using the following `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/927` where `927` is the channel id. You could get the list of videos on that channel using `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/927/videos`. The default response from the Vimeo API is in JSON.

Since this is tagged with vimeo-android, I suggest using the official [Vimeo Java library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) to help facilitate network requests. You can follow the ReadMe and the included sample app to help you getting started.